# Counting the frequency of characters in a file. C++

Tags: c++, character, frequency

The task is to print the (given text file) encountered Latin characters using the frequency table (without distinguishing between uppercase and lowercase letters) to file f1. The table must be sorted alphabetically.
So far my program only counts the letter A. I'm having problems with creating the loops which go through the whole alphabet and prints the table into another file, could you help me with those?

```
#include <stdio.h>
const char FILE_NAME[] = "yo.txt";
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int   count = 0;  /* number of characters seen */
    FILE  *in_file;    /* input file */

    /* character or EOF flag from input */
    int             ch;

    in_file = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
    if (in_file == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open %s\n", FILE_NAME);
        system("Pause");
        exit(8);
    }

    while (1) {
        char cMyCharacter = 'A';
        int value = (int)cMyCharacter;
        ch = fgetc(in_file);
        if (ch == EOF){
            break;
        }
        int file_character = (int) ch;
        if (file_character == value || file_character == value+ 32) {
             count++;
        }
    }

    printf("Number of characters in %s is %d\n", FILE_NAME, count);
    char cMyCharacter = 'A';
    int iMyAsciiValue = (int)cMyCharacter;
    cout << iMyAsciiValue;
    system("Pause");
    fclose(in_file);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just edited it.

Comment: He asked "Could you help me with those?" I guess, the assumption is that the presence of a question mark constitutes a question. However, questions which are isomorphic to "Can you do my homework?" don't quite qualify...

Comment: It's really not clear what help you need. You say you're having problems and ask us to help you with them, but your code doesn't exhibit any of the problems you discuss. You also don't tell us what problems you're having specifically.

Comment: Is that C++ really? Ah yeah, I did not see `cout << iMyAsciiValue`.

Answer (score 2):

First, get an array of size 26 for frequencies of a to z

```
int freq[26] = {0};
```

`freq[0]` for 'a', `freq[1]` for 'b', etc.

Second, change

```
if (file_character == value || file_character == value+ 32)
```

to

```
if (file_character >= 'a' && file_character <= 'z')
```

for all the lower-case alphabets (i.e. 'a' to 'z').

Third, get index and count by

```
freq[file_character - 'a']++;
```

, `file_character - 'a'` calculates the index, and the rest does count.

Fourth, print the `freq` array.

Fifth, add

```
else if (file_character >= 'A' && file_character <= 'Z')
```

for upper-case characters, and change subsequent codes accordingly.

<sub>It is your homework, you should try to figure out the whole program yourself. I hope this answer provides enough hints for you.</sub>

Comment: don't forget to change all values to lowercase